# Platform Event Trigger won't execute in subscriber org but in scratch org

Tags: trigger, managed-package, platform-event, subscriber

In my Managed Package, I have a trigger for the Platform event `Notification__e`. The publish behavior is **Publish Immediately**.

When I publish an event via Workbench or Developer console in one of the subscriber orgs (where the package is installed) the trigger is **not executing most of the time**. In namespace-enable scratch org it is always working.

> NOTE: How do I know that the trigger is not executing? 
>   `Latest Processed Id` is not changing on the Subscriptions related list after the publishing event. I checked after a
>   considerably long time, taking asynchronous processing behavior of
>   Platform event Triggers into account.

Comment: When you say "Latest Processed Id is not changing" you really mean it stays the same as it was before the triggering of the platform event? I only ask to discover if this is what you mean rather than "it doesn't change to the ID I got back when publishing" in case there is some other processing in your org that could cause other triggering of the platform event (so the ID may not match your expectation)?

Comment: @PhilW, Latest Processed Id is the same as it was before publishing platform event.

Comment: I am not trying to match it with Salesforce Id returned in workbench @PhilW

Comment: is trigger getting into error state?

Comment: Can you clarify what "*not executing most of the time*" looks like. Does the trigger fire occasionally? Only briefly after deployment? Only on Tuesdays?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal, Trigger subscription is in running state

Comment: @DanielBallinger, We fired platform event and trigger worked for 2-3 times and then it stopped working. Trigger subscription state is in Running state.

Comment: What does the problem org look like in terms of remaining event allocations? It might be that they have exceeded the limit and the resulting error is missed. I'd try subscribing to the same event via another mechanism to see if it is just the trigger not firing or a larger problem with the event.

Comment: @DanielBallinger, We are testing our app in QA org. So there is no such thing as a limit exceed. We are publishing event through the workbench, the maximum event we published was around 50 to 60 events which is too less than the applicable limit

Comment: Did you find anything? I have a similar issue I discovered, and I recorded a video where I can prove this happens

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZtS1iYSkz6-DqjAcaHM1yE1hbGM3brcr/view?usp=sharing